# How do I implement zooming for a Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming, scale

I'm doing a project for school in witch I have to simulate an ant colony and also show it in a graphics user interface.

The whole project is almost complete but I neet to implement a zoom feature for my jPanel.

I've found a thread on this site with basically what I need.Here's the link: 
 [Zooming in and zooming out within a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543453/zooming-in-and-zooming-out-within-a-panel?answertab=active#tab-top)

What Thanasis made in that thread is what I basically need but I have no Idea how to implement it inside my code with the other classes.

I am a newbie in Graphic User Interface and we are basically learning and understanding it by doing this project so forgive me if the answer is Super easy and I'm asking for the answer.

I can provide code for the Pannel and Window classes.

I've allready tried launching it without anything thinking that it will work directly on my jpanel but it didn't of course.also tried to call it in my main but that didn't work either. Here's my paintComponent from my panel . I basically do this for everything that shows(ants, colony, food).

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    int tailletab = this.gri.getTab().length;
    //On récupère le tableau de la Grille
    int[][] gril = this.gri.getTab();
    int taillecarre;
    int xcol = this.colo.getPos().getX();
    int ycol = this.colo.getPos().getY();
    int xsou = this.source.getPos().getX();
    int ysou = this.source.getPos().getY();
    if(tailletab<=50){
      taillecarre = tailletab/4+2;
    }else{
      if(tailletab<60){
        taillecarre = tailletab/5+1;
      }else{
        if(tailletab<70){
          taillecarre = tailletab/7+1;
        }else{
          if(tailletab<80){
            taillecarre = tailletab/8;
          }else{
            if(tailletab<90){
              taillecarre = tailletab/10;
            }else{
              taillecarre = tailletab/13;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<tailletab; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<tailletab; j++){
        if(gril[j][i]==0){
          if(j==xcol && i==ycol){
            g.setColor(new Color(102, 51, 0));
            g.fillRect(xcol*taillecarre, ycol*taillecarre,taillecarre,taillecarre);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(xcol*taillecarre, ycol*taillecarre,taillecarre,taillecarre);
          }else{
            if(j==xsou && i==ysou){
              g.setColor(Color.RED);
              g.fillRect(xsou*taillecarre, ysou*taillecarre,taillecarre,taillecarre);
              g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
              g.drawRect(xsou*taillecarre, ysou*taillecarre,taillecarre,taillecarre);
            }else{
              g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
              g.drawRect(j*taillecarre, i*taillecarre, taillecarre, taillecarre);
            }
          }
        }else{
          g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          g.drawRect(j*taillecarre, i*taillecarre, taillecarre, taillecarre);
          g.fillRect(j*taillecarre, i*taillecarre, taillecarre, taillecarre);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better and quicker help post [mcve] of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Andreas Holstenson in the link you provided is better than Thanasis' because you shouldn't override `paint` but `paintComponent` as you correctly did, and Thanasis doesn't overwrite the transformation but tries to be dumb-clever about not progressively updating the transform. If you lost me, just forget that answer altogether.

Otherwise, the choice of whether to use `AffineTransform` or not does not matter as the result is the same. Arguably, `AffineTransform` is easier to use.

To answer your question, put the additional scale/translate code at the top of that method and all graphics drawn after that should be zoomed (even if if you use `g` instead of `g2`).

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // No need to widen it to public
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    AffineTransform oldTransform = g2.getTransform();
    try {
        float zoom = 0.5f; // shrink
        // Note that transforms are in reverse order
        // because of how matrix multiplications work.
        AffineTransform newTransform = new AffineTransform();
        // 2nd transform: re-center
        newTransform.translate(getWidth()  * (1 - zoom) / 2,
                               getHeight() * (1 - zoom) / 2);
        // 1st transform: zoom (relative to upper-left corner)
        newTransform.scale(zoom, zoom);
        g2.transform(newTransform);

        // Draw here
    } finally {
        // Try-finally is probably not required, but ensures that the transform
        // gets restored even if an exception is thrown during drawing.
        g2.setTransform(oldTransform);
    }
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help!! The zoom only shrinks my stuff though. I also was looking for something that helps me zoom while the window is opened. either with a button or just a scrool of the mouse.. And I tried adding a button with no real result...would you be able to help me further? Thank you very much for the help you brought so far !!!

Comment: `zoom<1` shrinks, `zoom>1` enlarges. Move it to the top of the class to make it a value you can adjust at runtime. Look into how to adjust zoom automatically when you resize the window or scroll the mouse.